# Lower execution time for apache log parser in Python

Tags: python, performance

I have an school assignment where I were tasked with writing a apache log parser in Python. This parser will extract all the IP addresses and all the HTTP Methods using Regex and store these in a nested dictionary. The code can be seen below:

```
def aggregatelog(filename):
    keyvaluepairscounter = {"IP":{}, "HTTP":{}}
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
                result = search(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s*.*"(\b[A-Z]+\b)', line).groups() #Combines the regexes: IP (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) and HTTP Method ("(\b[A-Z]+\b))
                if result[0] in set(keyvaluepairscounter["IP"].keys()): #Using set will lower look up time complexity from O(n) to O(1)
                    keyvaluepairscounter["IP"][result[0]] += 1
                else:
                    keyvaluepairscounter["IP"][result[0]] = 1
                
                if result[1] in set(keyvaluepairscounter["HTTP"].keys()):
                    keyvaluepairscounter["HTTP"][result[1]] += 1
                else:
                    keyvaluepairscounter["HTTP"][result[1]] = 1

    return keyvaluepairscounter
```

This code works (it gives me the expected data for the log files we were given). However, when extracting data from large log files (in my case, ~500 MB) the program is VERY slow (it takes ~30 min for the script to finish). According to my teacher, a good script should be able to process the large file in under 3 minutes (wth?). My question is: Is there anything I can do to speed up my script? I have done some things, like replacing the lists with sets which have better lookup times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. Use "re.findall()" instead of storing returned regex data in array as such:

```
for data in re.findall(pattern, text):
    do things
```

instead of

```
array = re.findall(pattern, text)
for data in array:
    do things
```

I also read the entire file in one go:

```
file = open("file", "r")
text = file.read()
```

This implementation processed the file in under 1 minute!

Answer (score 0):

At minimum, pre-compile your regex before the loop i.e.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s*.*"(\b[A-Z]+\b)')
```

then later  in your loop:

```
for line in file:
                result = search(pattern, line).groups()
```

you should also consider optimizing your pattern especially the `.*` as it is an expensive operation